# Open SwiftUI view only if location permission granted

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view (say V) in which a user answers a few questions and their location is recorded. However, the answers only make sense with the user's location.

So what I want is that when the user clicks on a button on the parent view, it takes them to V and immediately asks them for the  location permission. If they accept, they can continue on to answer the questions, but if they deny, they navigate back to the parent screen.

I know I can navigate back to the parent screen with `self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()`.

But how do I know when the user has accepted or denied the permission since `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is an asynchronous function?

I'm following [this](https://www.progressioapps.com/get-user-location-on-ios-with-swift/) tutorial on getting a user's location on iOS with Swift.

Code for my LocationService:

```swift
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
    func didFetchCurrentLocation(_ location: GeoLocation)
    func fetchCurrentLocationFailed(error: Error)
}

class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate

    init(delegate: LocationServiceDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
        self.setupLocationManager()
    }

    private func setupLocationManager() {
        if canUseLocationManager() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        }
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        if canUseLocationManager() {
            print(CLAuthorizationStatus.self)
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func requestPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    private func canUseLocationManager() -> Bool {
        return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
        if let location = locations.last {
            let geoLocation = GeoLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            delegate.didFetchCurrentLocation(geoLocation)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        delegate.fetchCurrentLocationFailed(error: error)
    }

    deinit {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

struct GeoLocation {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`CLLocationManagerDelegate` has also the following method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
}
```

This method is called every time the authorization status changed. I would also like to recommend you implementing your `LocationService` as an `ObservableObject` instead of using delegate approach.

Comment: Why would the `ObservableObject` approach be better?

Comment: Because the `View` object in SwiftUI is a `struct` and it is not good idea to use `struct` as a delegate because it is value type. You can read about it, for instance, here: https://medium.com/tech-travelstart/could-struct-be-a-delegate-in-swift-fd86f5adbe16